# knockout.js Return TEXT from multiselect dropdown instead of VALUE

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use knockout to give the user simple feedback on what selections they have made.

My current code returns the VALUE from the multiselect dropdown which doesn't mean anything to the user. I would rather want to display the TEXT of the SelectedItem they have chosen.

Any ideas?

Current behavior (showing the VALUE not the TEXT) is at Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4tK2/

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: multipleSelectedOptionValues" id="CollectionStatusIds" multiple="multiple" name="CollectionStatusIds" size="5">
<option value="1">ACTIVE</option>
<option value="2">ARRANGEMENT</option>
<option value="23">CONSISTENT PMTS</option>
<option value="9">UNABLE TO CONTACT</option>
</select>
```

knockout.js

```
var viewModel = {multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(),};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it, with the built in bindings. But you can do this (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4tK2/7/):

html:

```
<div style="float: left; padding: 2px;">Collection Status:
    <br />
    <select data-bind="selectedOptions: multipleSelectedOptionValues, options:options, optionsText:'name'" id="CollectionStatusIds" multiple="multiple" name="CollectionStatusIds" size="5">
    </select>
</div>
<div style="float: left; padding: 2px;" id="ko-display">
    <div data-bind="text: multipleSelectedOptionValuesDisplay"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var VM = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.options = [
         {name:"ACTIVE", value:1},
         {name:"ARRANGEMENT",value:2},
         {name:"ATTY INVOLVEMENT",value:16},
         {name:"BROKEN PROMISE",value:17},
         {name:"CLIENT ISSUE",value:3},
         {name:"CONSISTENT PMTS",value:23},
         {name:"UNABLE TO CONTACT",value:9},
     ];

     self.multipleSelectedOptionValues = ko.observableArray();
     self.multipleSelectedOptionValuesDisplay = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.multipleSelectedOptionValues(), function(val){
            console.log(val);
            return val.name;
        });
     }, self);
}

 ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Also, note that `self.multipleSelectedOptionValues` should be an observableArray, rather than an observable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that how KnockoutJS work with `select`..knidly check that [example in documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example_3_dropdown_list_representing_arbitrary_javascript_objects_not_just_strings)
You need first to declare `observableArray` with your select options and bind the selected option to `observable` object..

***DEMO***

```
 var viewModel = {
     items: ko.observableArray([{
         value: 1,
         text: 'ACTIVE'
     }, {
         value: 2,
         text: 'ARRANGEMENT'
     }, {
         value: 16,
         text: 'ATTY INVOLVEMENT'
     }, {
         value: 17,
         text: 'BROKEN PROMISE'
     },

     {
         value: 3,
         text: 'CLIENT ISSUE'
     }, {
         value: 23,
         text: 'CONSISTENT PMTS'
     }, {
         value: 9,
         text: 'UNABLE TO CONTACT'
     }

     ]),
     multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(),
 };
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[***JSfiddle Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4tK2/8/)